# How to stop an input-waiting Windows batch process in Java?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a Windows batch file `simple.bat` which produces some output in stdin, and ends with a `pause`. I want to run this batch file and then process the output in my Java code.

```
// create a Java process with simple.bat
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c simple.bat");

// get the output from the process p
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);
    builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}

String result = builder.toString();
```

The problem with the above code is that `simple.bat` ends with a `pause` and that makes `p` still hanging in there waiting for the key to be pressed. As a result, eventually `reader.readLine()` will be blocked and never returns.

Unfortunately, `simple.bat` is passed on to me as-is. I cannot remove the `pause` line.

I can add

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
p.destroy();
```

after the `exec("cmd /c start simple.bat")` line to terminate the process `p` before processing its output. What if the batch file is run on slow machine? I am seeking advice is there a better way then asynchronously stopping the process. Thank you very much!!

Comment: OK, you can't remove the pause line. But how about reading the content of the batch file, creating a new (temporary) one but skipping the pause line and executing the temporary batch without the pause?

Comment: Are you sure you run `cmd /c start simple.bat` instead of `cmd /c simple.bat`?  The former opens a separate window and the output written to this window won't be returned in your BufferedReader.

Comment: @LukeWoodward you are right. My bad. Should be `cmd /c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script doesn't require any input sent to it, and you are running it as `cmd /c simple.bat`, then the simplest thing to do is to close the process's standard input:

```
p.getOutputStream().close();
```

I ran a quick test myself, and this dismissed the `pause` and let the script terminate.  You will of course have the extra line `Press any key to continue . . .` in your output, but I imagine you can deal with that.

Comment: thanks for the magic! I can deal with the extra line!! SO is great! (Newbie question: I don't have the reputation to upvote your answer, so I will just accept the answer, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Destroying the process can be correct as a fallback. You will have to think about how you would prefer your application to fail: is aborting to soon worse than a hanging process? Which of the failures will the user actually notice?

In most cases both of the above are undesirable.

If you know you have reached the pause (based on the last `readline()`), you can actually write to the process. This can be done by getting an output stream `Process.getOutputStream()`. I haven't been able to test this, but normally pause should also react to characters written this stream.

Comment: Um, the questioner isn't destroying the thread.  He's destroying the process.

Comment: @LukeWoodward oops, will adapt the answer.

Comment: @Thirler thanks for the idea of checking if I have reached the pause (i.e. look for "Press any key to continue...") to quit the loop.